# Pegando valor de um input e passando pra outro de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tela para venda de produtos, com isso tenho um botão para adicionar produto a ser vendido, esse botão traz um select (para escolher o produto a ser vendido) e um input (que vem o valor do produto)

Até ai tudo certo, mas estou com dificuldade no seguinte ponto:

Quero pegar com o `onchange` do `select` o valor do produto e passar para esse input ao lado.

Dessa forma:

```
function showValue(value) {
    var table  = $('.value-prod');
    $.post('ajax/value_prod.php', {value: value, select: true}, function(return){
        $(table).val(
            return    
        );
    });
}
```

Isso funciona em parte, o que acontece é que se eu adicionar um outro produto, ele vai substituir o valor do input anterior pelo do segundo select. E eu não quero isso.

Segue uma imagem de exemplo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura html adicionada quando clicado no botão "produto":

```
<div class="form-inline">
<label>Novo Produto</label>
<input class="form-control" name="prod_qtd[]" placeholder="Quantidade" type="number">
<select class="select-here form-control" name="prod_id[]" onchange="showValue(this.value)"><option value="" selected="">Selecione um produto</option>
    <option value="5">Pneu</option>
    <option value="6">camara de ar</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control value-prod" name="prod_value[]" value="" placeholder="Valor" type="text">
<a href="#" class="remove_field"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></a>
```

Comment: Posta a estrutura do HTML que é adicionado a cada produto na pergunta também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira que resolveria esse problema é mudar a chamada do evento para:

```
onchange="showValue(this)"
```

pois assim você passará a referência do elemento `select`, não apenas seu valor; e na função `showValue`, a ideia seria você primeiro buscar o elemento pai `div.form-inline` para poder buscar dentro deste o elemento `input.value-prod`, assim você selecionaria o campo `prod_value` que está na mesma `div` do `select` que foi alterado. O código seria algo como:

```
function showValue(element) {
  const prod_value = $(element).parent(".form-inline").children(".value-prod");

  $.post(
    'ajax/value_prod.php',
    {value: element.value, select: true},
    function (data) {
      prod_value.val(data);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara me ajudou muito.